# Substring Session ID from HTTPResponse using PHP

Tags: php, httprequest, httpresponse

I'm using PHP's HTTPRequest to call a webservice with the following code:

```
<?php
$req = new HTTPRequest
('http://webrates.truefx.com/rates/connect.html?u=user&p=pass&f=html&q=dfrates');
echo $req->getResponseBody();
?>
```

I receive the HTTPResponse when browsing this link as:

```
user:pass:dfrates:1298580682944
```

Note the Session ID after the last colon.

First, am I using HTTPRequest correctly?  Instead of echoing the response, should I send to another variable?
Second, I need to make subsequent HTTPRequests referencing the session ID in the first response.  How do I substring that session ID from the response and use it in follow up requests?

Thanks much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stick them in variables

```
 list($user,$pass,$rates,$session) = explode(":", $req->getResponseBody());
```

Now you can reuse them when you do subsequent requests.

Note the above code does not handle error condtions at all. You probably want to check that first before exploding the result.